# Adding time into a .plot file without adding a new line using awk

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I am writing a shell script that runs the command mpstat and iostat to get CPU and disk usage, extract information from those and put them into a .plot file to later graph them using bargraph.pl. What I am having troubles on is when I go use awk to get the time from mpstat like this

```
mpstat | awk 'FNR == 4 {print $1;}' >> CPU_usage.plot
```

It will prints a new line at the end of the code. I tried using printf as this is working for my other lines of codes to get the specific information needed without adding a new line of code, but I don't know how I can format it. Is there any way to do this with awk or any other method that I can use to accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

When use the command mpstat this is what bash returns

```
Linux 3.4.0+ (DESKTOP-JM295S0)  04/30/2017      _x86_64_        (4 CPU)

03:56:43 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest  %gnice   %idle
03:56:43 PM  all    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  100.00
```

This is what I'm trying to accomplish, take the time, usr, sys, and idle and put them into a file called CPU_usage.plot. This is what I wanted to put into the file:

```
03:56:43     0.00     0.00     100.00
```

What I got instead is:

```
03:56:43
0.00     0.00     100.00
```

This is my code:

```
mpstat | awk 'FNR == 4 {print $1;}' >> CPU_usage.plot 
mpstat | awk 'FNR == 4 {printf " %f", $4;}' >> CPU_usage.plot 
mpstat | awk 'FNR == 4 {printf " %f", $6;}' >> CPU_usage.plot 
mpstat | awk 'FNR == 4 {printf " %f\n", $13;}' >> CPU_usage.plot
```

Comment: show the input data and the expected result

Comment: edited in the original question with my code, input date, and expected results, and what I got instead.

Comment: man awk: print  Prints the current record.  The output record is terminated with the value of the ORS variable. ORS     The output record separator, by default a newline.

Comment: Any reason, why you don't print the 4 arguments in one statement?  Avoiding repeated calls of mpstat, which by chance would have different values.

Comment: I'm pretty new to bash so I've been trying different ways to the format to prints out correctly to work with bargraph.pl. But RomanPerekhrest already answered my question so thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following ***awk*** approach:

```
mpstat | awk 'NR==4{print $1,$4,$6,$13}' OFS="\t" >> CPU_usage.plot
```

---

Now, `CPU_usage.plot` file should contain:

```
03:56:43    0.00    0.00    100.00
```

Comment: just another question if you don't mind. I am doing the same thing for iostat but iostat does not provide a time, is there a way for me to do it too?

Comment: @ThienNguyen, *for me to do it too* - to do what?

Comment: Oh sorry. I wanted to do the same thing using awk to retrieve information from mpstat but now using iostat instead. However, I am expected to have a time stamp but when you run iostat, iostat does not provide a time. So is there a way for me to awk a time into it along with kB_read/s and kB_wrtn/s?

Comment: and what time? random time, London time or system time? And what is `iostat` output?

Comment: Sorry, system time. And this is iostat's output: 
Linux 2.6.32-100.28.5.el6.x86_64 (dev-db)       07/09/2011

avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           5.68    0.00    0.52    2.03    0.00   91.76

Device:            tps   Blk_read/s   Blk_wrtn/s   Blk_read   Blk_wrtn
sda             194.72      1096.66      1598.70 2719068704 3963827344
sda1            178.20       773.45      1329.09 1917686794 3295354888

Comment: @ThienNguyen, I see, it looks much that you can start new question with `iostat` issue. Start new question, send me a link and I'll try to help you